# Disable network connection using batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, networking

I need to enable/disable network connections on windows with a batch file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with Windows PowerShell. [Here's a page with examples.](http://forums.techarena.in/software-development/1118216.htm)

Probably you want to use the last one on that page.

**Update**

A little more searching reminded me about netsh, which is a more appropriate tool than either PowerShell or devcon:

```
netsh interface set interface "Local Area Connection " ENABLE
netsh interface set interface "Local Area Connection " DISABLE
```

I'm not sure which version of Windows you're using, but here's the [netsh doc for XP](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/netsh.mspx?mfr=true) to get you started.

Comment: I had to change "Local Area Connection " to "Local Area Connection", but this works great

Answer (score 2):

You may use [devcon](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;Q311272) (from MS).

Usage

```
  devcon disable *INTERFNAME
```

[Here](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/1886-enable-disable-a-device-from-the-command-line) is a simple tutorial for your intended usage.

HTH!

Comment: I had to use this as netsh didnt recognize any of my devices when the computer was booting.

Answer (score 1):

netsh wlan connect ssid=*SSID HERE*name= *network name HERE* interface="Wireless Network Connection"

and

disconnect interface="Wireless Network Connection"

both actually work in windows 7